# PHP how to echo alert before header redirects to another page

Tags: php, header, echo

I'm trying to make a functionality where, after the user logs in, an alert will popup saying "welcome USER_NAME", after which it will redirect to the user profile page.

I tried the sleep & flush methods, and even ob_start & ob_end_flush methods..but nothing seems to work, it just redirects to user profile after logging in without echoing the alert. Is there any way of fixing this problem?

Here is the part of the code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
``$_SESSION['user'] = $uname;
``echo "<script> alert('Welcome $uname')</script>";
``header("location: dashboard.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Better write the redirect in Javascript (`document.location = ...`), after the `alert()`, that should work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP's redirection with `header("Location:xxx.php");` functionality does not allow any browser output.

You can use Javascript redirection (taking in consideration of program logic).

```
echo '<script>
alert(' + '"Welcome ' + $uname .'");
window.location.href="welcome.php";
</script>';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
echo 'alert("Welcome $uname");';
echo 'window.location.href = "index.php";';
echo '</script>';
```

try upper instead of below code

```
``echo "<script> alert('Welcome $uname')</script>";
``header("location: dashboard.php");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Although your answer is valid, it is the same as another answer posted 12 minutes ago. That makes your posting less useful. If you think that's wrong, you could explain in your answer why your answer is better than the other.

Answer (score 1):

For simple javascript alerts, you can simply use `window.location.href` but if you need to show some advanced popups like bootstrap modals or sweet alerts you can use `setTimeout` which evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.

```
echo "<script> alert('Welcome $uname');
window.setTimeout(function(){


    window.location.href = 'http://fullpath/dashboard.php';

}, 3000);
</script>"
```

You can use javascript alert and then redirect it after specific timeout

Comment: Better put the `alert()` last, and hope it doesn't block the timer. Or simply test your code in https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: You may be right but it is also helpful to show other popups like bootstrap models or sweet alerts with this

Comment: Bootstrap popups are nothing like `alert()`, the latter will block Javascript execution, the former doesn't.

Comment: Yes. this is what is I say. If you need to show bootstrap models or sweet alerts then it would be helpful

Comment: No, it is not helpful. There's no point in just waiting 3 seconds before a redirect, when you use `alert()`. Test your code, see what it does! I do understand that you want to show a message for 3 seconds, and then redirect, but that's not what your code does.